# making a curve for border

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I was wondering, if you could help me with something in Photoshop.
I want to bend an image, as it will be used for a border on the site, however I cannot find any guides (Maybe because the keywords I use matches for different guides).

I tried to use `Warp tool` but unfortunately this tool makes more a mess, maybe because I don't understand that tool.

I also tried the `Shear filter`, but this doesn't give the result I was looking for.

If you can help me or point out a guide that explains this, then please :)

I have attached an image that explains how I want it.

[image]

Thanks for the answers, however I ended up with remaking the texture myself, even if it costs some time, I ended up discarding the bended images as it did not fit onto the project as I hoped.

Thanks again, I do keep these tutorials from you as they might come in handy later :)

Answer (score 3):

There's a few ways to do this, the easiest way if you're in a newer (I believe it was first introduced in CS 5) is with the Puppet Tool.

1. Select the layer with the shape to bend
2. Go to Edit > Puppet Warp
3. Pin on one end, pin on the middle, pin on the other end.
4. Move one of the end pins

For greater control put more pins around the middle to smooth it out.

[image: Puppet Tool]

Comment: Well, I tried this as well but it messes up the texture, I want to keep that as much alive as possible, however it seems to be that I will have to make a new one from scratch. since I do not see a very easy way at this moment.

Comment: @user19613 edit your post with a screenshot of what exactly is going on when it "messes up" and we can try to help you solve the issue

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do something similar, unfortunately this way will not simply take what you have and curve it, but merely tile and mask what you have, which may still work for you, but is generally best for flat patterns.

I would make your image a pattern `Edit -> Define Pattern` and then after you create an object you can go to that layer's `Layer Style` and add a stroke and then change that stroke to use that pattern (NOTE: You can move the pattern around using the move tool while the dialog window is open):

[image]

Then check `Layer Mask Hides Effect` under the `Blending Options`

[image]

Now create a layer mask on your object and simply get ride of everything except the corner and turn the `fill` to 0.

[image]

Comment: I've tried this earlier, but that is indeed more for static approach, since the image I use is more complex it just will be put under each other.

Comment: Yeah, and I figured as much, but I was hoping it might be some new information for others.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, however Ryan's answer will work. The problem you are running into is you are working on a small version of your original border. If you increased the size of the border's resolution you are attempting to bend, Ryan's solution will work. This way you have more control of the pixels and your not letting Photoshop calculate them for you.

Comment: Hi, yes that is exactly what the issue was there since I used a very small texture it is hard to bend correctly using that method, but it works better on bigger textures.